# Using Ionic Framework, how do you refresh from localstorage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have a problem with refreshing from localStorage.

I have list of items. I can display them. I add one item to array and display.

Everything works fine. I can display. I can see that another object was 
added to items array.

When I close and reopen app. The alert shows object exists and has correct number of items. Only problem is I dont see the items now in the view.

Is this $scope problem or async problem. The array exists..

Edit:

I have array with three items. I push to localstorage, first. 
then use data from localstorage to bring into '$scope.items'.

In the view,  the data is shown from '$scope.items'. Everything 
works as expected. I turn off app turn back on, And the array 
loads properly from localstorage. This is not a problem.

Now, the view has ability to add to array. I can add to array,
Again loading from localstorage. There is an alert, which shows
that the array has one more object. I can add another item and .....
All of them show up in the view. All updates come from localstorage.

I turn app on and off, there is nothing in the view. This is done
on a phone so I cant check localstorage.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: what alert? what object? ... you might be a mystical "Merlin" but we can't read minds yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem. It was a ng-repeat issue.

```
<div ng-repeat="row in [1,1,1] track by $index">
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post any code so I will just do my best to help. are you fetching items from local storage and setting to to a $scope variable? also fetching the item from local storage on app load and put it in a service or do it before the view that needs the data enters the view.
like this:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    $scope.items = localStorage.getItem('youritem');
});
```